# Open extension library dialog from client side java script

Tags: javascript, xpages

How to open extension library dialogue from client side javascript?
I use

```
XSP.openDialog("#{id:myDialog}");
```

and it works perfect if I call it somewhere from xPage itself...
But how do I open the dialogue from client side javaScript library?

```
Error: TypeError: dlg is undefined
```

I need to call it from a function in client side javascript library:

```
  <a onclick="return showMyDialog();">Click it</a>
```

Thank you...

Comment: XSP.openDialog() *is* client side. Show us your function.

Comment: I know it's not right but this is the function:    function showDELinks(){
 XSP.openDialog("#{id:myDialog}");
 return true;
}

Comment: Is the function defined on the same XPage - or in a separate js lib?

Comment: yes, it's in separate client side javascript library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"#{id:myDialog}"` is only interpreted if it is part of the actual XPage or Custom Controls.  In Script Libraries no interpretation occurs.

I use CSJS libraries all the time with a model that declares a class like this:

```
if(!myDialog) {
    var myDialog = {
        id : "",
        show : function() {
            XSP.openDialog(this.id);
        },
        close : function() {
            XSP.closeDialog(this.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the XPage or Custom Control I put a scriptBlock like this:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
myDialog.id = "#{id:myDialog}";
    ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess the problem is that your function is defined in a resource outside of the XPage itself. Therefore `#{id:myDialog}` is not being parsed (correctly).

I suggest that you pass the id of the dialog to your function. So define your function like this instead:

```
function showDELinks(dialogId){ XSP.openDialog(dialogId); return true; }
```

You can then call your function like this:

```
<a onclick="return showDELinks("#{id:myDialog}");">Click it</a>
```

**Update**

This simple demo works. Here's the XPage:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/csLib.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <a onclick="return showDELinks('#{id:myDialog}');">Click it</a>

    <xe:dialog id="myDialog"></xe:dialog>

</xp:view>
```

Here's the csLib:

```
function showDELinks(dialogId){ XSP.openDialog(dialogId); return true; }
```

So something else is wrong in your code.

Comment: same error           Error: TypeError: dlg is undefined

Comment: Per's correct. The id: syntax will not work in a Script Library, because it cannot identify the context it's running in. That's why you're getting "dlg is undefined". If the SSJS is written directly on an XPage / Custom Control, you'll have a much longer dialog name rather than dlg, including some "id_" bits